# Make a request from one container to the second container with localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two docker-compose files set up - one for the frontend application, and one for the backend.

Frontend runs on 3000 port and is exposed on 80: `0.0.0.0:80:3000`
Backend runs on 3001 port and is exposed on the same port also publicly: `0.0.0.0:3001:3001`

From the host machine, I can easily make a request to the backend:
`$ curl 127.0.0.1:3001`

But I cannot do it from the frontend container - nothing is listening on that port because those are two different containers in different networks.

I tried to connect both of them in one network - then I can use the IP of the backend container, or a hostname, to make a valid request. But it's still not the localhost. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Docker, localhost points to the container itself, not to your computer. There are a few ways to do what you want. But none of them will work with localhost from a container.

The cleanest way to do it is by setting up hostnames for your services within the yml and set up your applications to look for those hostnames instead of localhost.

Let me know if you need examples and I will look for them at home and post it here to you.